# Background-color change on hover event not working

Tags: html, css

I got a problem with the CSS hover-event.
I created a page with a navigation bar at the top. For compatibility reasons I had to move away from nav and changed it to a simple div. (nav is not known in IE8, but it still has to be working there.)

```
<div class="nav">
 <ul>
   <li> <a> Something </a>
      <ul>
        ....
      </ul>
   </li>
   ....
 </ul>
</div>
```

That resulted in making the hover on my navigation bar not working anymore. But it's not, that nothing is working, only the first one of the following lines does not do it's job anymore. The background simply does not change.

```
.nav ul li:hover { background: #BFBFBF; }  - not working
.nav ul li:hover > a { color:#FFFFFF; }    - working perfectly fine
.nav ul li:hover > ul { display:block; }   - working perfect as well
.nav ul {
  background: #404040;
  list-style:none;
  padding:0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  text-align:left;
  display:block;
}
```

I double checked basically everything I know, suspected or found, that could be the source of my issue, but I was yet unable to get it back working.
I tried using background-color instead of background, without success.
I want to do it without having to use anything besides HTML and CSS, which should be possible, since it worked, when I still was using the nav-element.

I am noob to css, maybe I'm missing some really simple detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put your code on a fiddle?

Comment: please provide your code in demo or jsfiddle..thanx

Comment: What other kind of CSS do you have for you `.nav ul li`? Maybe it doesn't have any dimensions?

Comment: @putvande: `.nav ul li` only has `display:inline` to be horizontal. Gonna add `.nav ul` CSS in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than modifying the nav bar content, just try to change the animation for the thing which you are pointing at, I mean that rather than hovering the `<li>` component just make the text in it hovering

```
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .2s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}
.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Try defining the `<a>` element and hovering it as the whole `<li>` won't hover with multiple overlapping CSS formats

Comment: That works perfectly fine and looks better than anything I achieved so far, thanks to `transition`, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See I created something in html. And your code is working.
Its good if you can paste your html

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .nav ul li:hover {
        background: #BFBFBF;
    }

        .nav ul li:hover > a {
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
        }
</style>
```

```
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>Li 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Li 2
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Li 3
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: I cannot use `nav` because it has to be working in IE8 as well. Had that solution, because I was only looking at the page in higher IEs and Chrome. Then I used IE8 once an realized I won't be able to use `nav`.