# I have a few css issues with a dropdown menu I've created

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, parent-child

I get the feeling that these are really simple problems, however I'm new to coding and can't work out how to fix them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Firstly, the hyperlink text is currently the only clickable part of the dropdown menu. I want to be able to click the whole section of the menu that the text sits in, i.e the individual parts separated by the 1px borders. I'd also like these sections to change color when the cursor hovers over them, but I'm not sure which part of the css to change if I want to achieve this.

Secondly, the padding creating the space between my main menu links is being included in the link hover function. Is there a way of spacing out the links that doesn't cause the subpages to drop down when I hover over the white space to the left of them? (This seems like the opposite of my first problem)

Finally, part of the css I've written makes any of the parent menu links that have been clicked stay highlighted purple while the viewer is on that page. This was intentional, however now that I have child pages in the dropdown menu, they all stay that color too when the parent page is clicked. Is there a way of fixing this? it would be ideal if both the parent link and the specific child link stayed highlighted purple whilst the viewer was on a that particular child page.

The website link is www.lucieaverill.co.uk

Here is the code :

HTML:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
<?php $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary'); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* header navigation menu */

.header nav ul{
display:block;
float:right;
width:auto;
margin-top:15px;
padding: 0;
background-color:#ffffff;
list-style:none; 
}

.header nav ul li {
float:left;
padding-left:50px;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

.header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited{
color:#A084BD;
}

/*  dropdown menu */
.header nav ul ul { 
position:absolute; 
left: -999em; 
}

.header ul li:hover ul {
left:auto;
width: 200px;
}

.header ul li ul li {
float:none;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.header ul li ul li a {
font-size:11px;}

/* end dropdown menu */

/* end header navigation menu */
```

UPDATE! ------------------------------

I think I've made some progress based on what various people have been saying about a tags. I've managed to reach the point where the hover effect changes the a tag's color, however the padding is a little off, and I can't work out why. I've tried setting the padding-right value to "auto", as I don't think it can have a specific value as each link varies in length. 
Obviously, I want the padding to extend to the very end of the menu at the right hand side, but I can't make this work.

There also seems to be some odd spacing between the color of each link, and at the very bottom of the menu.

I'm surprised to see that the transition between colors is smooth and gradual.. I don't think I have any css that tells it to act like this.. is there a way of making it more instant?

The web link again, is www.lucieaverill.co.uk

```
/*  dropdown menu */
.header nav ul ul { 
position:absolute; 
left: -999em; 
}

.header ul li:hover ul {
left:auto;
width: 200px;
}

.header ul li ul li {
margin-left:0px;
float:none;
}

.header ul li ul li a {
background-color:#FF3F55;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:auto;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
font-size:11px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.header ul li ul li:hover a {
background-color:#ededed; }

/* end dropdown menu */
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/ here is a great place to look up information and tutorials on everything web-related: CSS, html, PHP, mysql, etc

Comment: Set your demo at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background-color change on hover event not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982962/background-color-change-on-hover-event-not-working)

Comment: I made some updates and some of your suggestions seem to be working, there are a few other problems I've run into, which I've described in an update to the question above. Can anyone figure these out?

Answer (score 0):

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/7osxLvdc/):

Remove the padding of `li` and add the required padding to `a` tag.
the clickable problem will be fixed.

```css
/* header navigation menu */

.header nav ul{
display:block;
float:right;
width:auto;
margin-top:15px;
padding: 0;
background-color:#ffffff;
list-style:none; 
}

.header nav ul li {
float:left;
padding:0px;
}

.header nav ul li a{
padding:20px 25px;
}

.header nav ul li a:hover {
    color:white;
    background:black;
}



.header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
.header nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited{
color:#A084BD;
}

/*  dropdown menu */
.header nav ul ul { 
position:absolute; 
left: -999em; 
}

.header ul li:hover ul {
left:auto;
width: 200px;
}

.header ul li ul li {
float:none;
padding-left:10px;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.header ul li ul li a {
font-size:11px;}

/* end dropdown menu */

/* end header navigation menu */
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <nav class="site-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">submenu</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem I'm having is when I'm adding the a tag - `.header nav ul li a{padding:20px 25px;}` css, it's affecting the parent menu links above it as well. I'm not sure if its anything to do with me not adding `<a` tags in the html. I'm not sure how I would go about doing this as I'm using php to target the wordpress menu links rather than adding each link manually with an `<a`